# Why does not Clojure allow us to write functions unordered?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp, clojurescript

One of the things that I don't like in Clojure is that I need to define functions in order like this:

```clj
(defn a [] 1)
(defn b [] (+ 1 (a)))
```

If Clojure was like Java I could write like this(unordered).

```clj
(defn b [] (+ 1 (a)))
(defn a [] 1)
```

But if I do compiler will throw error that **a is not defined...**

***What is the main reason that Clojure designed in this way?***

*P.S: I know Clojure provides **declare** function but I don't want to declare all functions in the namespace.I would like to write functions like I do in Java, JavaScript etc.*

Comment: Rich Hickey discusses the rationale [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2467359).

Comment: Rich Hickey's note on this referred to by @SamEstep is extremely confused about CL: in particular you are not going to be able to fix the (non-)problem in CL the way he seems to imply.

Comment: I expect this problem will be resolved when [immutable namespaces](http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Release.zFuture) arrive, whenever that may be.

Comment: You mean: **If Clojure were like Lisp ...**

Comment: @tfb Indeed, basically from the comment "Clojure, like many Lisps before it, does not have a strong notion of a compilation unit." onward, when CL is used as the representative of those many Lisps.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you find this little helper useful

```clj
(defmacro autodeclare [& exprs]
    (let [dfns# (filter #(and (list? %) (= (first %) 'defn)) exprs)]
      (map (fn [e]
             `(declare ~(second e))) dfns#)
      `(do ~@exprs)))
(autodeclare
   (defn c [] (b))
   (defn b [] (a))
   (defn a [] :a)
   (prn :no_defn))
(c)
user>  :a
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: true, but I want to encourage people to build their own solutions. This is easily possible in clojure and the question itself is already answered in the comment section.
In lisp you can build your own tools, if the deafult behaviour doesn't cut it